# Cannot get metadata from mp3 when file is totally in memory

Tags: mp3, metadata, javasound

I am using JavaSound with Mp3SPI support.
The one I am using is JavaZoom
http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html

When I create an AudioFileFormat from a file constructor I can get the duration of the mp3.

```
File file = new File("path/to/file.mp3");
AudioFileFormat format = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);
format.properties().get("duration"); // works fine
```

But I have a file in memory and I cannot write it to disk...So when I create the AudioFileFormat from an InputStream I dont get the duration.
Heres my code:

```
ByteArrayInputStream barray = fromNetwork();
AudioFileFormat format = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(barray);
format.properties().get("duration"); // does not work
```

**But if I try to play the audio, it works fine.**

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used mp3agic and everything worked fine.

[Mp3Agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic)

```
ByteArrayInputStream ba = IOUtil.toByteArrayInputStreamUntilTheEnd(new FileInputStream(file)); 
InputStream is = new InputStream(ba); 
Mp3Metadata md = new Mp3Metadata(is);
```

Comment: Hello @Patison, I wrote this code a long time ago and I dont rememebr exactly what I did. But I can see that I have in my code a constructor that takes an InputStream. I have edited the answer so you can see it.